# How to classify elements in a folder and its subfolder in Matlab for matching purposes

Tags: matlab

I have a folder `dat` that could contain `n` subfolders and these contain various `.dat` files

I need to get all the files in these subfolder stored in a data structure `myarchive` that contains the `file_name`, its `subfolder_name` and a object `resulanalysis` that is the result of a my analysis script

The purpose of this operation is to obtain `file_name` and `subfolder_name` of the entries  in `myarchive` that matches a generic `result`

With this code I'm able to get all the analysis result of the files contained in the current folder and I have the matching function, but I don't know how to solve the described classification problem.

```
files = dir('*.dat');

for file = files'
    im = load(file.name);
    result=myanalyzer(im);
end
```

Could someone help me?

If someone has a better strategy that could meet my problem is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to through all the subfolders, load the .dat file, run some analysis and see if the result matches a certain value. If it matches you wan to save the names of the subfolder and the file in a data structure myarchive. If that's the case, here's the code:

```
topfolder = '...\dat\'; % Specify the full path to the dat folder
cd(topfolder)
subfolderlist = dir;
subfolderlist = subfolderlist(3:end); % because the first two results are '.' and '..'
counter = 0; 

for ii = 1:lenght(subfolderlist)
    cd([topfolder,subfolderlist(ii).name])
    filename = dir('*.dat');
    im = load(filename); % assuming there is only one .dat file in the folder

    if myanalyzer(im) == result
        counter = counter + 1;
        myarchive(counter).subfolder_name = subfolerlist(ii);
        myarchive(counter).filename = filename;
    end
end
```